# workflow_run is never trigged by pull_request

Tags: github, workflow, pipeline

I have two very simple GitHub workflows for testing proposes. `deploy-test-first` which runs always on `pull_request` and `deploy-test-second` which should run on completion of `deploy-test-first`

The `deploy-test-second` however never runs. What Am I missing? How do I make it work?

```yaml
name: deploy-test-first

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  deploy-test-first:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: deploy-test-first
        run: echo 'deploy-test-first'
```

```yaml
name: deploy-test-second

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [deploy-test-first]
    types: [completed]
    branches: [develop]

jobs:
  test-deploy-second:
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: test-deploy-second
        run: echo 'deploy-test-second'
```

Both workflows are suppose to run on non-default branch develop in PR.

Comment: Because of [this](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#triggering-a-workflow-from-a-workflow) maybe?

Comment: And do you have the workflow files on the default branch yet?

Comment: The `deploy-test-second` workflow runs as expected when both workflows files are on the default branch(main). My goal is to run both workflows on non-default branche(develop) inside a PR so I can run the checks not on the default(main) branch which is also a production one.

Comment: Can you use the [`branches`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#limiting-your-workflow-to-run-based-on-branches) filter for that?

Comment: I already tried to use branches filter `branches: [develop]` (the branch on which both workflows are running) for `workflow_run` in `deploy-test-second` but no luck.

Comment: But if the first workflow only runs on pushes and PRs into `main`, the second workflow will never trigger if it only listens to workflow runs on `develop`, no?

Comment: The first workflow should run on pushes to `main` branch and on PR's that are targeting `main` branch. The second workflow should run on completion of the first workflow that runs on `develop` branch. Or I don't understand what you mean? :) I updated the post above.

Comment: I understand that if you set `on.workflow_run.branches` to `develop`, it triggers only when a workflow run finishes *on that branch*, but if your supposed trigger runs on the `main` branch, as you write, the second workflow will never trigger.

Comment: Do you mean by supposed trigger the first workflow? If so, that workflow runs on `develop` branch as well as the second workflow.

Comment: So for the scenario where you want both workflows to run, is the first running on a PR from `develop` into `main`?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I've created a minimal [test repo](https://github.com/bewuethr/workflow-run-test) and copied your exact workflows into the `main` branch. Then I created a `develop` branch, added a change and opened a [PR](https://github.com/bewuethr/workflow-run-test/pull/1) into `main`; this triggered the [first workflow](https://github.com/bewuethr/workflow-run-test/actions/runs/3282800859), and when that finished successfully, it triggered the [second workflow](https://github.com/bewuethr/workflow-run-test/actions/runs/3282811125).

Comment: @BenjaminW.Thanks for looking it it. It's a mystery for me. I tried to create a brand new repo, this time a public one (the original one, that doesn't work is private) and the public one actually works as expected. It's exactly the same as the private one. It's beyond me what the private repo doesn't work. Trying to figure out why though.

Comment: Hmmm, I made mine private and pushed another commit, and it still works, so it's at least not it being private alone that's causing it.

Comment: The only other difference I see that that might causing this is that the original repo that doesn't work is running in my organization GitHub, where might be some settings that for some reason blocks the `workflow_run` to detects completion of the first first repo.  I have admin access so I can can look around what might cause it, but I wasn't able to find anything yet. All the settings seems to be pretty much identical to my personal GitHub. I tried to run a different workflow with very similar setup inside the Organization GitHub, but with no luck.

Comment: The workflow isn't running in a fork, is it?

Comment: No. It is not..

Comment: Then I don't know, without seeing the exact configuration. There are org- and repo-level settings for actions, but I really can't think of one that would allow actions to run in general, just not that trigger...